# Spring MyBatis: как обновить сразу несколько записей одним запросом?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

У меня есть несколько записей, для которых нужно обновить поле. Список уже есть. Как это можно сделать через `MyBatis -> Example?` Нужно обновить весь список при помощи одного запроса.

На данный момент, у меня так:

```
List<Cat> сats = сats = getсatsTree(id, сats);

CatExample example = new CatExample();
CatExample.Criteria criteria = example.createCriteria();
cats.forEach(p -> {
    p.setStatus(itemStatus);
    criteria.andIdEqualTo(p.getId());
});
catMapper.updateByExample(...); //здесь я зашёл в тупик
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, логика обновления списком оказалась довольно неожиданной, и работает она так:

```
    //список для обновления
    List<Cat> itemCats = catsTree(itemId, itemCats);

    //ритуальные действия создания критерия поиска по базе
    CatExample example = new CatExample();
    CatExample.Criteria criteria = example.createCriteria();
    criteria.andIdIn(itemCats.stream().map(Cat::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    //создаём объект-шаблон, по которому будем менять параметры
    Cat toUpdate = new Cat();
    //меняем необходимые параметры
    toUpdate.setStatus(itemStatus);

    //выполняем апдейт, в который кладём шаблон и критерий поиска по базе
    CatMapper.updateByExampleSelective(toUpdate, example);
```